# Calculate sum of values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the sum of some values in jQuery. I do this with

```
var sum = 0;
$(".total").text(sum += parseInt($(".numbers").text(), 10));
```

but is is not making a sum. I have tried the following which is also not working?

```
var sum = 0;
$(".total").parseInt(sum += parseInt($(".numbers").text(), 10));
```

How can I simply calculate the sum here?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M7ghD/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum values you need to iterate `.numbers` elements:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.numbers').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($.text(this), 10);
});

$('.total').text(sum);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/M7ghD/5/

Answer (score 1):

You have to take each value of `class=numbers` and sum it.

Try:

```
var sum = 0;

$( ".numbers" ).each(function() {
  sum=sum+parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
})

$(".total").text(sum);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M7ghD/4/)

Comment: Thanks, same as VisioN's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/M7ghD/1/:

It seems doing `$(".numbers").text()` will give you a concatenated string of all your `span.numbers` at the same time (= '421293'). You have to loop through the elements and sum them up:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.numbers').each(function(){
  sum += parseInt($(this).text(),10);
});
$(".total").text( sum );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as also

```
  var sum = 0;
  $('.numbers').each(function() {
        sum += Number($.text(this));
  });

 $(".total").text(sum);
```

**parseInt(string)** will convert a string containing non-numeric characters to a number, as long as the string begins with numeric characters.

**Number(string)** will return NaN if the string contains any non-numeric characters

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m9em3/)